# #ajax callback is not working in drupal8

Tags: 8, ajax

In **Drupal\module_name\Form\AddTemplate** form

```
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\InvokeCommand;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

$form['fieldset']['add_new_event_btn'] = 
             array(
                '#title' => t('Add new event trigger'),
                '#value' => t('Add new event trigger'),
                '#type' => 'button',
                '#attributes' => array(
                    'style' => 'margin-top:20px;width:200px',
                    'id' => 'imageBtn',
                    #'OnSubmit' => 'my_function();return false;'
                    ),
                '#ajax' => array(
                    // Function to call when event on form element triggered.
                    'callback' => 'Drupal\module_name\Form\AddTemplate::enable_event_trigger',
                    // Effect when replacing content. Options: 'none' (default), 'slide', 'fade'.
                    'effect' => 'fade',
                    // Javascript event to trigger Ajax. Currently for: 'onchange'.
                    'event' => 'click',   
                    'progress' => array(
                        // Graphic shown to indicate ajax. Options: 'throbber' (default), 'bar'.
                        'type' => 'throbber',
                        // Message to show along progress graphic. Default: 'Please wait...'.
                        'message' => NULL,
                    ),
                ), 
            );
```

And in **`enable_event_trigger`** function

```
/*
     * function to enable the new event trigger box
     */
    public function enable_event_trigger(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state){ 
        //Instantiate an AjaxResponse Object to return.
        $ajax_response = new AjaxResponse();
        $ajax_response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand('#edit-email-subject', 'val', 'adipoli'));

        //Return the AjaxResponse Object.
        print_r($ajax_response);exit;
        return $ajax_response;
    }
```

But it didnt worked ,its **not even going to the callback function**  any idea ??

**UPDATE**

**`I was forget to include js via library ($form['#attached']['library'][]) in the form , thanks :)`**

Comment: Did you check this with F12 in your browser?

Comment: yea , i check the console that anything is printing

Comment: I mean the ajax request and response in Network.

Comment: @4k4 yes ,  i checkd ,

Comment: And what is in the response?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43743/discussion-between-icecreamjelly-and-4k4).

Comment: Sorry i was **forget to include js** via library (**$form['#attached']['library'][]**) in the form , thanks :)

Comment: could you update your post please? So no one will be confused!

Comment: what js did you need to add?