# hook_form_alter ajax callback never fired

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

My use case is the following : I've an autocomplete widget to a referenced entity and I want the value of an other autocomplete widget to be selected when the first one is done.

I'm aware of [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/138625/whats-the-event-triggered-after-an-autocomplete-has-run-and-how-to-retrieve-the/228150#228150) topic and of the *autocompleteclose* ajax event, but was not able to see any ajax request fired in the browser's console.

Since it's my first attempt to altering drupal's forms and using its AJAX API, I decided to try the simplyest test as possible on a text field, but, was still not able to see any ajax request in my browser's console... Here's my example code :

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id){
    $form['my_field']['#ajax'] = array(
        'event' => 'change',
        'callback' => 'my_ajax_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'my-wrapper',
     );
    $form['my_field']['#attributes'] = array('style' => 'color:red');
}
```

I can see my form is altered because my field label is red... But when I type in it, the ajax callback is not triggered and I do not see any error in the console.

Jquery lib is loaded and ajax is working because I can see ajax requests when using autocomplete fields... Anyway I tried to attach the drupal core ajax lib as mentionned in [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/211097/ajax-callback-is-not-working-in-drupal8) post ($form['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.ajax';), but nothing changed...

I'm obviously missing something here... Has anybody an idea ?

Comment: You need to look at `$form['my_field']`'s children - `$form['my_field']` itself will be a wrapper, hence adding classes applies the desired CSS, but the AJAX needs to be applied to the widget itself, which is further down the hierarchy. Same sort of principle as http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27767

Comment: Hi @Clive, I've tried to add the '#ajax' array to the widget children When I use dump($form['field_subtitle']['widget']['#ajax']), it outputs the following array :  "event" => "change",   "callback" => "my_ajax_callback",   "wrapper" => "my-wrapper", but there is still no ajax request fired... Have you got an idea ? Thanx for helping by the way...

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue?

Comment: Yes ! I had to use the following to target the form field : $form['my_field']['widget'][0]['target_id']['#ajax']. Doing that way the ajax request was fired. Hope this helps...

Comment: Wow, after reading at least 10 posts on how to di this... this is the correct answer: $form['my_field']['widget'][0]['target_id']['#ajax'] - awesome.